# What new features or enhancements can we expect in the upcoming Magento versions in 2024?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, database

As we anticipate the upcoming Magento versions in 2024, several exciting features and enhancements are expected to shape the platform's evolution. While specific details may depend on official announcements and community contributions, here are some general areas where Magento is likely to see improvements:

1. Enhanced Performance and Scalability
2. Headless Commerce Innovations
3. Advanced AI and Machine Learning Integration
4. Progressive Web App (PWA) Enhancements
5. Security Upgrades and Compliance Measures
6. Advanced Customer Experience Tools
7. Innovations in Mobile Commerce
8. Community-Driven Contributions
9. Efficient API Development
10. Sustainability Initiatives

Answer (score 0):

Magento is an open-source e-commerce platform, and updates and new features are announced by Adobe (a company that owns Magento). As per the latest report, Magento is developing advanced features available in the latest version of **Magento 2** which is **2.4.7**. Here are some of the top enhancements and newest features described.

1. Enhanced security system for full-page cache
2. Appropriate platform alignment
3. Improved indexing and better scalability
4. Increased customer experience
5. Improved quote detail view
6. Sorted GraphQL abilities
7. Compatible PWA studio version
8. Synced Page builder version